# signal SIGABRT when testing on device, it works on simulator. Easy code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4

I'm not experienced in programming.

I was trying to do an easy iOS app (just to try some tutorials) that works as a "sendmail"

Easy interface with just 1 button that when pressed, it opens the MFMailComposeViewController window.

That's the code.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

-(IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"



@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"example@example.com"];
    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [picker setSubject:@"TEST SUBJECT"];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

On the iPhone and iPad simulator it works like a charm.
But when testing it on the device it crashes giving signal SIGABRT and showing as evidence that part of main.m:

```
  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

with a "Thread 1 - Signal SIGABRT" near.

Any tip?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: I would suggest placing a breakpoint with all exceptions and break on throw just so that you can see where it crashes before you get thrown to the main.m

Comment: If you use the Breakpoint Navigator to set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions, the odds are that it will stop where the **real** problem is and give you an error message that has better information.

Comment: Forgot to say that the app gives SIGABRT signal when I press the button. The app loads perfectly, but when I press the button it crashes.

Comment: The first breakpoint gives thread signal to that piece of code: MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

Answer (score -1):

Two things to try:

1. Clean the files <`SHIFT+CMD+K`>
2. Uninstall the file from your device and try with the cleaned one

Comment: Tryed with cleaning the files, but nothing to do.

Answer (score -1):

Right at the beginning of showPicker: add this :

```
if [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]
{
  // Your code
}
else
  NSLog(@"No mail account configured on device or not supported");
```

Comment: I hadn't a mail account configured. SOLVED ! Thanks mate

Comment: No problem :) Now please accept either iOS-Deveoper's answer or mine to complete the topic :)